# How to eliminate other possibilities of $p$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$  be a finite group, $p$ be  the smallest prime divisor of $|G|$, and $x \in  G $ an element of order p. Suppose
$h \in  G $ is such that $hxh ^{−1} = x ^{10} $. Show that $p=3$

My try:

Since $o(x)=p$ and $hxh^{-1}$ and $x$ being conjugates have the same order we have $o(hxh^{-1})=o(x^{10})=p$

Also $o(x^{10})=\dfrac{p}{\gcd(10,p)}=p$

Then $\gcd(10,p)=1$ then $10^{p-1}\equiv 1(\mod p)$

I can see that $p=3$ satisfies the equation .Also $p\neq 2,5$.How to eliminate other possibilities of $p$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $H=<h>$ and $X=<x>$, and $Aut(X)$ is the group of automorphisms of $X$

because $x^{10}=hxh^{-1}$ translates the fact that $H$ acts on $X$ by conjugation, in other words, we have a homomorphism $\varphi : H → Aut(X)$ for any element $h$ and any element $t$ we have $\varphi(h)(x)=hth^{-1}$.

This latter group has order $p−1$ and the first group has order with all prime divisors $\geq p$ whence $\varphi$ is the trivial homomorphism. This means that $hxh^{-1} = x$. But we are given that $hxh^{-1} = x^{10}$. It follows that $x^9$ is the identity element, so $p = 3$.

---

**Another proof** (simplification of the notions used in the first proof)

One can see that $x^{10}=hxh^{-1}$ implies that $x^{10^q}=h^{q}xh^{-q}$ using Fermat's little theorem combined with $q=p-1$ we get $x=h^{p-1}xh^{-(p-1)}$ . Let's now take $q$ as the order of $h$, as we know the order of $h$ is coprime with $p-1$ hence there exist some $u$ such that $u(p-1)\equiv 1 \mod q$ and then:
$$x=h^{p-1}xh^{-(p-1)}=h^{2(p-1)}xh^{-2(p-1)}=h^{u(p-1)}xh^{-u(p-1)}=hxh^{-1} $$

which gives you the result.

Comment: why is $\phi $ trivial please explain in the 1st proof

Comment: I  have one problem why $o(range(\phi))$ divides $o(H)$ ?rest is clear

Comment: Because $|Range(\varphi)||Ker(\varphi)|=|H|$ it's a well known result about homororphisms

Comment: yes i have understood

Comment: Your proof starts "It's clear that $x=hxh^{-1}$ implies that $x=h^qx^{10^q}h^{-q}$."  I think you mean "$x^{10}=hxh^{-1}$"

Comment: why does the first group i.e H has order with all prime divisors $ \ge p $ ?

Comment: Then we have to use that $ |Range(\varphi)| $ divides $ p-1 $ as well as $ | H | $ right ? then again smallness of $ p $ would survive us right ?

Comment: Yes we have  that $|Range(\varphi)|$ divides $p−1$ as well as $|H|$ so it divides their $\gcd$ using that $p$ is small we have $\gcd(|H|,p-1)=1$ and thus $|Range(\varphi)|=1$, hence $\varphi$ is trivial

Comment: what if $ o(H) $ is multiple of p-1 ?

Comment: This is not possible because all prime which divides $|H|$ are greater than $p$ and all prime which divides $p-1$ are less that $p$ so $|H|$ and $p-1$ are co prime

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23410/discussion-between-vikrant-desai-and-elaqqad).