# Let $G$ be a finite group, $p$ the smallest prime divisor of $|G|$, and $x\in G$ an element of order $p$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, group-actions

Suppose $h\in G$ is such that $hxh^{−1}=x^{10}$. Show that $p=3$.

I am trying to solve this problem using group actions. Let $H$ and $X$ be the subgroups of $G$ generated by the elements $h$ and $x$, respectively. We have a homomorphism $\varphi\colon H\to\mathrm{Sym}(X)$, where $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$ is the symmetric group of $X$. What group action should I take? Does the given equation in some way imply that we can take the conjugation action of $H$ on $X$ or vice versa? I am stuck here. This question has already been asked before but the answers use methods other than group actions. I am more inclined towards using group actions.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Shouldn't $hh^{-1}$ be equal to the identity of any group?

Comment: @Diya $hxh^{-1}$ needn't equal $x$: not every group is abelian.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something here? Take the dihedral group $G=D_{11}=\langle x,h: x^{11}=1=h^2, hxh^{-1}=x^{10} \rangle$. Then $|G|=22$, which is not divisible by $3$.

Comment: here is a [proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225559/how-to-eliminate-other-possibilities-of-p)  of your question

Comment: @NickyHekster you're missing the condition in the title that the order of $x$ is the smallest prime divisor of $|G|$.

Comment: OK, I now see that you splitted the question over the title and post.

Comment: Ohh I noticed that now. I understand it might have caused some confusion.Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H$ acts on $X$ by conjugation. This follows from $hxh^{-1} \in X$: it's easy to check that this implies $h^ix^jh^{-i} \in X$ for all $i, j$, i.e. $h'x'h'^{-1} \in X$ for all $h' \in H$, $x' \in X$. Checking that this action satisfies the other definitions of an axiom is also easy to check (it's the same as checking that any conjugation action is a valid action).

So by orbit-stabiliser, $|\text{Orb}(x)|$ must divide $|H|$, and so must divide $|G|$. So, either $|\text{Orb}(x)| = |X| = p$, or $|\text{Orb}(x)| = 1$, since if $1 < |\text{Orb}(x)| < p$ then any prime factor of $|\text{Orb}(x)|$ will be a smaller prime divisor of $|G|$ than $p$.

But we cannot have $|\text{Orb}(x)| = |X| = p$, since then $\text{Orb}(x) = X$ - but the identity $e$ is not in the orbit of $X$, since $h'eh'^{-1} = e$ for all $h' \in H$. So we must have $|\text{Orb}(x)| = 1$, i.e. $h'xh'^{-1} = x$ for all $h' \in H$. In particular, $x^{10} = hxh^{-1} = x$, and so $x$ has order dividing $9$. Since $x$ has prime order, it must have order $3$, i.e. $p = 3$.